# Azure webapps rewriting backslash to slash

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am wondering how to solve this peculiar problem:

I have a Flask webapp with the following:

```
@app.route("/tags/<tagname>")
def tag(tagname):
    return lookup(tagname)
```

Problem is one of the tags in the source system has a backslash:   abc\def

Using urlencode i get the url path `"/tags/tagname/abc%5Cdef"`

Building my docker image locally, this works wonderful and I can return the value of `abc\def`.
However when I use this container in a Azure webapp for containers, it responds with a 404.

Using a catchall-route i have found that
`"/tags/tagname/abc%5Cdef"` is translated to `"/tags/tagname/abc\def"` locally, but "/tags/tagname/abc/def" in Azure.  Of course this breaks as this route is not defined and a 404 is returned.

I have now no idea how to handle the "\" in Azure webapp.

Comment: I'm having the same problem intermittently. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping it with a few different combinations

```
abc\\def
abc^\def
abc^^\def
abc^^^\def
abc&\def
```